# OpenNMS QUICK INSTALLATION GUIDE UBUNTU Initialize OpenNMS .... FAILED

Tags: ubuntu, failed-installation, opennms

Ubuntu install 18.04 updated
installed Oracle Java SE Development Kit 8
Installed gnupg, curl, wget
used the QUICK INSTALLATION GUIDE UBUNTU script at the very end I get Initilize OpenNMS .... FAILED.
Ubuntu Newb...
I don't know where to start to trouble shoot.
I don't think it is even running.

Answer (score 0):

There is some contention among the OpenNMS community about using scripts to install OpenNMS.

I'm old, so I like using good ol' apt.

I [made a video on](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7sWgucBhsWc) installing OpenNMS that you might find helpful. It covers all the steps you need to get it installed. It's pretty simple: once you add the repository and the GPG key to your sources you can install the application. Then you need to make a change to the PostgreSQL database for permissions, and then you can initialize the database and get going with OpenNMS.

Comment: Thank you very helpful. I had to re-install Ubuntu and the entire script package. I don't know what I missed but it was 'something' Your VIDEO is top notch.